# how can i inherit model type for new type in type script?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

i want to inherit model type from another model type in typescript

export model need to inherit from another model

```
export type A extends B={
  a:number,
  b:String
};

export type B={
  c:string

};
```

it shows error in visual studio code and react ts compilation error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type aliases do not support inheritance. You can do something similar using intersection types:

```
export type A = B & { a: number, b: string };

export type B = {
    c: string
};
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCcC8cBCcBkcA3nAIYBccAdgK4C2ARsFADRwOUDKMUAllQHM4AXwDcAKHGhIsBMlR5sRcXFVwAxpQDOPfgPFigA)

Or you can use interfaces (in this case it really does not matter if these types are type aliases or interfaces):

```
export interface A extends B { a: number, b: string };

export interface B {
    c: string
};
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTlFSQBMBnOAITgG85MAuOJAVwFsAjNAGjk+bkYUZAHM4AXwDcAKBmhIsRCjRZc1OjLja42QcLEzpQA)

Comment: @KelumSampathEdirisinghe you are welcomed. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 

Comment: @titan sure. i will after became my reputation 15 above. otherwise system do not allow me to upvote

Comment: @KelumSampathEdirisinghe you can still mark as answered (the tick under the vote count) that is not dependent on reputation